# Cannot execute jar built with gradle with correct Manifest

Tags: java, gradle, manifest, executable-jar

I have a JavaFx application and I cannot run it from both command line and windows explorer.I built the jar using Gradle, and checked for the manifest and it is correct. I tried everything from StackOverflow but it always complains that it cannot find the entry point from Manifest:

My main is located in src/main/java and it is called Main.

Here is the configuration for gradle:

```
group 'com'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'Main')
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the dependecies (I build an uber jar).
And here is the content of my manifest(created by gradle with the new line at the end):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

When I try to run it i get all the time this:
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Comment: If you inspect your Jar, is `Main.class` where you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly where it should be.

Comment: It must respect the structure of the project, and yeah the jar is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because you apply the `application` plugin, none of the customisations of the `jar` tasks are required.
So I recommend you remove them and check if it creates a valid jar then.

While I did not confirm by running it locally, I believe the customisation done in `from` is wrong and creates a busted jar.